# jquery autocomplete - how to display field 1 + field 2 and upon selected, just fill field 1 in textbox

Tags: jquery

I am working on c# application where I have implemented below function to display autocomplete feature which works fine. 
The only thing I want to do is, when upon search it displays item, those displayed items should be displayed as Field 1 + Field 2, but when user selects an item of that, Field 1 should be filled up for that textbox, so basically display item and filled up item should be different. 
Here is my working code.

```
<input type="text" id="txtInfo" class="form-control" >

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {$('#txtInfo').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: 'Controller/MyActionMethod' ,
        disabled: false,
        minChars: 0,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        deferRequestBy: 800,
        transformResult: function (response) {
            if (response != null) {
                return {
                    suggestions: $.map(response, function (dataItem) {
                        return {
                            value: dataItem, data: dataItem
                        };
                    })
                };
            }
        }          
    });
});
```

```
public JsonResult MyActionMethod(string query)
    {
            List<SelectListItem> MyIems = Session["myVal"] as List<SelectListItem>;
    //MyIems  has Text and Value, Text is the one I want to display and Value is the one which I want to get fill up 
    // in the txtInfo when user selects it. 
    // For example, if user searches and txtInfo displays text "Full Name", when he selects that, txtInfo should have 
    // filled up with "Value" of that item. 
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            List<string> displayResult = new List<string>();
            foreach (var r in MyIems)
            {
                if (r.Text.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()) || r.Value.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()))
                {
                if (!result.Contains(r.Value)) result.Add(r.Value);
               }
             }
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a delimiter e.g. pipeline, comma etc in your concatenated response and then split this value and show what you need.

**Example:**

```
var MyResponse = Field1|Field2|...n;
var SplitedResp = MyResponse.split("|");
alert(SplitedResp[0]); // has Field1 value
alert(SplitedResp[1]); // has Field2 value
```

**Update:** Assuming that you return a json object with a delimiter as I said before and a key name *label*, here is an example with all the methods you need, `focus`, `select`, `search` & `response`

```
$("#txtInfo").autocomplete({
            delay: 500,
            minLength: 2,
            source: "Controller/MyActionMethod",
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var SplitedResp = ui.item.label.split('|');
                $(this).val(SplitedResp[0]); // visible text to user
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var SplitedResp = ui.item.label.split('|');
                $(this).val(SplitedResp[0]);
                $(this).attr("custom_attr",SplitedResp[1]); // value of the selected result
            },
             search: function(){ 
                        // you can add a loading effect 
                        $(this).addClass('loading'); 
             },
             response: function (event,ui) {
              //you can check if the length of return has nothing
              //and inform user about that with a message.
            }            
});
```

Comment: I tried but could not succeed binding Text and Value through jquery. what changes do I make in my jquery function to display splitedresp[0] and when user selects that, fill out splitedresp[1] in textbox. I mean here what change should I make when I return this string. return {
                        suggestions: $.map(response, function (dataItem) {
                            debugger;
                            return {
                                value: dataItem, data: dataItem
                            };
                        })
                    };

Comment: Thanks, I tried exact above code but something is missing at my end, it did not load anything, basically it just keeps processing. I returned string with "|" from actionmethod. that works but somehow UI just keeps spinning. I tried exact above code. $("#txtInfo").autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: 'controller/myMethod' ,
            disabled: false,
            minChars: 0,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            deferRequestBy: 800,